# Adobe DTM Data Element Updating

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm looking for a way to dynamically update a pre-defined data element in DTM. Once the page loads and the data elements are initialized it is not possible to update them,  _sattelite.setVar() does not work. I can create a Data Element on the fly but it won't persist from page to page.Example:

```
var currElementName = this.getAttribute('data-analytics-tracking-name');
_satellite.setVar('custom link name', currElementName);
```

Any suggestions? I'm asking this because I'm going to be working with a MVC framework and I'd like to store some of the data in DTM data elements and update as views change. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to set a persistent data element to a new value, you need to first update whatever source the data element is based off of, and then use `_satellite.getVar('element_name_here')` to force evaluation of the data element.

The key here is that *on page load*, the order of operations for a persistent data element is basically:

1. Look for the satellite cookie and return that value
2. Look for the specified target for the **type** (e.g. **path** (js var) for **type** JS Object) and return that value
3. Return the default value

But when you *explicitly call* `_satellite.getVar('Example')`, the order of operations is instead:

1. Look for the specified target for the **type** (e.g. **path** (js var) for **type** JS Object) and return that value
2. Look for the satellite cookie and return that value
3. Return the default value

**Data Element Example:**

> **Name:** Example
>
> **Type:** JS Object
>
> **Path:** someVariable
>
> **Default Value**: default value
>
> **Remember this value for:** Session

So let's say I have on the page the following (set prior to DTM script tag):

```
someVariable = 'foo';
```

This will make available a data element named "Example" which you can reference with `%Example%` or `_satellite.getVar('Example')`, depending on the context.

For the duration of the session, the data element will have that value "foo".  So to change it, you would do the following:

```
someVariable='bar';
_satellite.getVar('Example');
```

You can call this within your own script somewhere, or if you want to throw this into the mix for e.g. a page load rule, you can add it as a condition inside a `Criteria > Data > Custom` code box (*note: if you put it here, add a `return true;` as 3rd line*), etc..

**As an alternative,** if you are feeling more adventurous, or need a work-around for your data element setup (e.g. your data element is type Custom Script and you need to sidestep the logic in there)..

When you have a data element configured to be persistent, it sets a cookie named

`_sdsat_[data element name]`

So in the example above, it sets a cookie named

`_sdsat_Example`

So, if you *really* wanted to, you can instead just update the cookie with the new value, and just let the default order of operations return the (now updated) cookie value.  (*note: since it's not possible with javascript to get the expiration of a cookie, if you are setting the scope to "Visitor", you can set the expiration to 2 years, [which is what DTM does](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/data_elements.html)*)

Comment: Hi Crayon Violent, thanks for the reply. I have gotten this to work for most situations but the one thing I'm struggling with is for a pre-defined data element that is set in a custom script by an anonymous function (scoped for page view). Is there is a way to update in this situation?     

   [code] return (function() { 
         try
     {
    var rvalue="initial data element value";
        } catch(e) {}
     return rvalue;
    })();

Comment: @MichaelJohns - You can find the initial value (if one exists) in the `_satellite.data.customVars` object. If it returns null / undefined, set it to your value and then return it. `if(!_satellite.data.customVars.rvalue) { _satellite.data.customVars.rvalue = 'initial data element value'; } return _satellite.data.customVars.rvalue;`

Comment: @MisterPhilip Thank you for that comment. I went into the data element editor in adobe DTM and set the Path to `_satellite.data.customVars.myVarName`. Now `_satellite.getVar('myVarName')` and `_satellite.set('myVarName', 'someval')` both work as I would expect them to.