# Conditional Data Element in Adobe DTM

Tags: tags, adobe, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

I wonder if Data Element returned values could be conditioned by the context.
To be more clear, If I'm using a Data Element value in a Custom Script rule, I set this method:
`_satellite.getVar('Data Element name');`
I want the returned value to be conditioned and the obvious way would be passing an argument to the same method, like:
`_satellite.getVar('Data Element name', argument);`
I would have previously set the Data Element to be conditioned by the same argument.
The DTM Object Reference reports this getVar method syntax:
`function (variable, elm, evt)`
but I think that neither 'elm' nor 'evt' arguments could suit my need.
Is this true?
Thanks

Comment: It sounds like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28218278/184595) might help you (the **Update** part, in particular). If not, then can you please provide more details about what you want? e.g. show an example of the code you'd have in the data element, and more code around how/why you'd be calling `.getVar()`

Comment: Thanks Crayon, you've been so helpful again. I didn't figure out that Data Element could return a function too, that could be conditioned! Thanks it works great.