# Adobe DTM Capturing ID from Class

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm new to Adobe DTM so please be gentle with me! What I'm trying to do is to have a Data element hold the value of the ID of a clicked button of class "b1".

```
<button type="button" class="b1" id="value 1">button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="b1" id="value 2">button 2</button>
```

1. How should my Data Element be set-up since I don't want any initial value in it?
2. How do I structure the Event rule to capture the value of the clicked button?

I do know that I have to set the tag/selector to .b1 with event type of "click" in the condition but how do I source the "ID" value of the clicked button and assign to the Data Element.

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example...

Create an **Event Based Rule**, name it whatever you want.

Within **Conditions**, for the **Event Type** select "click".

For **Element Tag or Selector** put "button.b1" (no quotes). This is basically the equivalent of a css (or e.g. jQuery) selector you'd use for targeting button elements that have class "b1".

**Note:** You may or may not need to checkmark the *Apply event handler directly to element* option, depending on how your site is setup and what all is already hooked to the elements.

Now, under **Rule Conditions** Criteria, choose "Data > Custom" and click the "Add Criteria" button, which will then show a **Custom** codebox section.

Within that codebox, enter the following:

```
var id=this.id||'';
_satellite.setVar('b1_button_id',id);
return true;
```

So the way this works is that within a condition, `this` should be a reference to the button that was clicked. So we use that, along with DTM's `_satellite.setVar()` method to set a data element called "b1_button_id" to the value of the button's id attribute. Then we return true to ensure that the condition is always true, so that this condition will not prevent the rule from triggering.

From there, in any of the sections of the rule, you can reference the data element with either `%b1_button_id%` syntax (like in one of the form fields for setting a var through DTM) or you can use `_satellite.getVar('b1_button_id')` within any of the custom code blocks in the rule.

**Note:** data elements created on-the-fly with the `.setVar()` method only persist for the duration/scope of the rule being evaluated. DTM does not have an officially documented way of creating or updating persistent data elements or setting any other features that you have available from the actual **Rules > Data Elements** section, but [there are some workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078790/adobe-dtm-data-element-updating) depending on what you want to do.

**Another Note:** You didn't specifically mention a need for this, but since it may be a next step that might come up.. as mentioned, within the context of a condition, `this` is a reference to the element for the event (in this case, the "click" event). If for some reason you need to reference `this` within a codebox in the **Javascript / Third Pary Tags** section, be aware that `this` will remain in context if you do **NOT** check the *Execute Globally* option, but if you **DO** check that option, then `this` will no longer be a reference to the event element.

If you need a reference to `this` AND you need the code to be executed globally, then you can create a data element following the instructions above, except just use `this` as the value, e.g.

`_satellite.setVar("this_reference",this)`

Then, within the codeblock you can use `_satellite.getVar("this_reference")` to get it.

Comment: is there a way to get _satellite.setVar("data element name", value); to remember for the session? I've tried setting an element up in the DTM UI (with "remember this value for" set to session) then updating it with .setVar().

Comment: DTM does not currently offer a way to set the scope of the data element when creating it on-the-fly with `setVar()`.  If you have a data element named `foo` in your interface, and then create one with the same name suing `setVar`, you will overwrite the one in the interface, not simply update it. Which is why it doesn't work for you like you tried

Comment: @FinbarMaginn There is a workaround for it though, see this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078790/adobe-dtm-data-element-updating

Comment: @FinbarMaginn also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161177/issue-updating-dtm-pre-defined-data-element-when-anonymous-function